# How to remove numbers from TokenStream in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, analyzer

I have written a custom analyzer that wraps a StandardAnalyzer with a Length. Now I want to filter out all terms that contain just numbers.
What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Is it on just one field?  If so, you can just use a FieldBridge to not add terms containing just numbers to the Document.

Comment: What is FieldBridge in Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

You may be in for a custom `TokenFilter`. Check out one of the simplest filters out there, the [LowerCaseFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseFilter.java). I think you'll find it easy to write your own along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PatternReplaceFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceFilter.html) to detect and remove numbers from the TokenStream by using a regular expression.